# AWS Lambda - Automatically de-provision users for a third-party application using SSO with Azure Ad as the identity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory

Let me explain my problem. The problem involves 2 cloud providers namely AWS and Azure. We have Azure AD running. A third-party product makes use of Azure AD authentication and allows users to sign in. When a user signs in to the third-party application, corresponding new users are created in the third-party application for each SSO user signing into the third-party application. However, if a user were to be removed from the Azure AD, the corresponding user created in the third-party application is not removed. I would like to automate the removal of the users somehow.

So we use **AWS extensively as the cloud provider**. We only use Azure AD which is bundled with an O365 subscription. **We do not have an Azure subscription.**

Most of our workloads are running on AWS. Ideally, I would like to make use of native AWS services to run this automation. We also have AWS SSO enabled with Azure AD as the identity provider.

Here is what I would like the workflow to be:

-A user is removed from an Azure AD group. When this happens, some workflow needs to be triggered which removes the corresponding SSO user in the third-party application.

Here are the approaches that I think will work:

**Option #1**: AWS lambda function which would remove the stale users from our third-party application.

**Option #2** Make use of the Azure AD SCIM endpoint from within the AWS Lambda function to trigger a sync of users between Azure AD and the third-party application.

This is the first time I am attempting something of this sort. I would be very grateful if someone could offer their comments on the approaches that I have listed above.

Do you happen to know if it's possible to invoke the SCIM endpoint for a third-party application in Azure AD, even if the application does not support SCIM natively?

I am open to other approaches as well.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Also, the following would help me:
-Any code samples which demonstrate how to authenticate to Azure AD from AWS lambda(Preferably Python but open to GoLang)
-Any articles which kind of demonstrate this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

For transparency, I work at Microsoft.

Azure AD/Entra doesn't have a SCIM endpoint(server), and in any case what you're actually needing appears to be the SCIM client which would then call AWS's SCIM server.

Is there a reason you aren't just configuring SSO and/or SCIM provisioning via the "AWS IAM Identity Center" app in the Azure AD/Entra Enterprise App Gallery? Using group membership/assignment as the scoping logic would require Azure AD/Entra Premium P1 licensing (to assign groups to an application), but if you don't have the licenses, then you could likely adjust your logic somehow to use one or more attribute values on the user instead to put the user in/out of scope.

Otherwise, you're going to have to write some portions of a SCIM client yourself to make these calls to AWS's SCIM endpoint - you can't go from  -> triggering AAD/Entra's SCIM client -> request to AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So to clarify, the application that i am talking about is called "SquadCast". Its an incident management tool similar to PagerDuty or Opsgenie. So what you are suggesting is that, instead of configuring SquadCast SSO with Azure AD as the identity provider, we instead configure SquadCast SSO with AWS Identity Center(since we already have SSO enabled in AWS as well)? Is that a correct understanding? Doing so would de provision users automatically once they are no longer available in AWS. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: Ah, nope. I did not accurately understand your scenario. 

You can either write something custom and run it in AWS (or wherever), or you can use Azure AD/Entra's User Provisioning service to manage the lifecycle of accouns in the SquadCast app. My original answer above can largely be reused, just replace references to AWS with SquadCast. AWS shouldn't have any role in this if you are using Entra as your IDP and use Entra's provisioning to manage SquadCast.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. So as i understand, User Provisioning service should do the trick for me. Is that a correct understanding? If yes, @Zollnerd, i would suggest that you update your original answer so that i can mark it as the answer.